# Django - Switch between boolean and integer in TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-modeladmin, modeladmin

I have some models in Django like this:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    ...

class ObjectFeatures(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('object', 'feature'),)
    count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    object = models.ForeignKey(...)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(...)

class Feature(models.Model):
    is_number = models.BooleanField()
    ...
```

I have an object, and in this object is an inline form in the admin panel with `ObjectFeature`. There you can select the feature you want to add from features, and the count of how many of that feature are available.

The `is_number` defines if the feature expects a number or, if false, a boolean (0 or 1 in count).

Is there anyway to display a checkbox in the `TabularInline` when it expects a boolean rather than an integer, though it's an `IntegerField`?

Another possibility is to define a boolean and an integer field in `object_features`. Is there a possibility I can show just one of those, based on the value in `is_number`?

In admin.py:

```
class ObjectFeatureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ObjectFeature
    can_delete = True
    verbose_name_plural = 'Object features'

class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ObjectFeatureInline,)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

IN your inline

```
    def new_field(self, obj):
        if type(obj.is_number) is bool:
            do stuff - as bool
        else:
            do other stuff , maybe check if int and so on...
    new_field.allow_tags = True
    new_field.short_description = 'is_number verbose'
```

add new_field to readonly_fields in inline

Comment: I want to be able to change the value in the admin panel tough. This solution will only give a readonly field. I'm searching for a way in which I can show the user a checkbox instead of a number input field, but only when the checkbox is appropriate.